# Not receiving telegram notification from zabbix

Tags: notifications, telegram, zabbix, media-type

I have been using Zabbix for a while now. I tried to configure the telegram media type so as to receive notifications. Due to some error, I'm not receiving any notification. While testing the media type this is the error that appears on the log. Please help me resolve this.

**Media type test log
00:00:00.000 [Debug] [Telegram Webhook] URL: https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage
00:00:00.000 [Debug] [Telegram Webhook] params: {"chat_id":"-xyxyxyxyxy","text":"{ALERT.SUBJECT}\n{ALERT.MESSAGE}","disable_web_page_preview":true,"disable_notification":false}
00:00:05.183 [Debug] [Telegram Webhook] HTTP code: 200
00:00:05.184 [Debug] [Telegram Webhook] notification failed: TypeError: cannot read property 'ok' of null**

Comment: check from zabbix server command line if it can connect to `https://api.telegram.org/`

Comment: Could you please share the command to do it? I'm not familiar with the command line.

Comment: `curl https://api.telegram.org/`

Comment: "curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above." But I am able to connect using the -k option.